# Symfony form AJAX return empty object

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, forms, symfony

I'm trying to create AJAX form with Symfony, but my form return empty object. When I send manualy writed text or array everything works fine. Where is the bug? I do something wrong with form or javascript code is the problem?

```
/**
* Renders the "new" form
* 
* @Route("/", name="demo_new")
* @Method("GET")
*/
public function newAction(Request $request) {
    $entity = new Demo();
    $form = $this->createForm(DemoType::class, $entity);

    return $this->render('default/new.html.twig', array(
            'entity' => $entity,
            'form' => $form->createView()
            )
    );
}

/**
*
* @Route("/", name="demo_create")
* @Method("POST")
*
*/
 public function createAction(Request $request) {
if (!$request->isXmlHttpRequest()) {
  return new JsonResponse(array('message' => 'You can access this only using Ajax!'), 400);
}

$entity = new Demo();
$form = $this->createForm(DemoType::class, $entity, array(
    'action' => $this->generateUrl('demo_create'),
    'method' => 'POST',
));

$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
  $data = $form->getData();
  return new JsonResponse(
          [
            'message' => 'Success!',
            'data' => $data 
          ], 200);
}

$response = new JsonResponse(
        array(
    'message' => 'Error',
    'form' => $this->renderView('default/new.html.twig', array(
        'entity' => $entity,
        'form' => $form->createView(),
    ))), 400);
return $response;
 }
}
```

and Javascript code:

```
  function initAjaxForm()
    {
    $('body').on('submit', '.ajaxForm', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type: $(this).attr('method'),
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serialize()
    })
    .done(function (data) {
        if (typeof data.message !== 'undefined') {
            console.log(data.data);
            console.log(data.message);
        }
    })
    .fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (typeof jqXHR.responseJSON !== 'undefined') {
            if (jqXHR.responseJSON.hasOwnProperty('form')) {
                $('#form_body').html(jqXHR.responseJSON.form);
            }

            $('.form_error').html(jqXHR.responseJSON.message);

        } else {
            alert(errorThrown);
        }

    });
});
}
```

Comment: "my form return empty object". You mean `$(this).serialize()` is empty? Or the response from the PHP code is empty? Please can you clarify exactly where the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue today with version 2.8 gonna leave this here in case it end up healping someone else i've added this to my form builder

```
/**
 * {@inheritdoc}
 */
public function getBlockPrefix()
{
    return '';
}
```